# Question about $\log_1 (1)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

In my college calculus class we just covered properties of logs, and I wanted to ask about them. Two of them are these:

For all $0 < a$: $$\log_a1=0$$
and for all $-\infty\leq b \leq \infty$: $$\log_11=b$$

So my question here is about $\log_11$. From the first property, $\log_11=0$ but from the second property, $\log_11=1$. Since 0 does not equal 1, how is this true?

Comment: There is no such thing as $\log_1$ and there is no such thing as $\log_0$.  These are not allowable bases.

Comment: We actually have $$\lim_{a\to 1}\log_a(1)=0$$ , but this is not $log_1(1)$ for the same reason why $$\lim_{a\to 0} \frac{0}{a}=0$$ is not $\frac{0}{0}$